# Any way to convert speech to text like google do for searchbox for iphone?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, speech-to-text, voice, webspeech-api

How to convert speech to text on iphone chrome browser. I have done using speech recognition API for android devices and desktops,laptop but this API is not working on iphone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has speech to text built in. Tap on any text entry field, when the keyboard shows tap on the 'microphone' button on the bottom row of the keyboard. Speak into the mike and watch the words appear.